# Reading CSV values and adding them to a dictionary, is there any better approach without the loop?

Tags: string, c#-4.0, csv, dictionary

```
  String[] S1 = miscParams.Split(";".ToCharArray(),
      StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

               for (int i = 0; i < S1.Count(); )
               {
                 miscparams.Add(S1[i], S1[i + 1]);
                 i += 2;
               }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please don't really do this in real program:

```
var miscparams = S1.Where((k, i) => i%2 == 0)
    .Zip(S1.Where((v, i) => i%2 == 1), (k, v) => new[] {k, v})
    .ToDictionary(e => e[0], e => e[1]);
```